# Azure Pipelines delete files and rename after IIS publish

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using Azure Build Pipelines i'm trying to publish an ASP.NET WebForms website to IIS.

Everything works, except that I have several images in a folder of my website (e.g. `/Images/1.jpg,2.jpg`, etc..) and I would like to delete all images from that folder except `2.jpg` and rename it to `1.jpg` after I've deployed the website (or during the release pipeline if that's possible)

Is there any way to do this in Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Write a PowerShell script for such complex tasks you want to do and make it one step in your pipeline.

Comment: i think powershell is the way to go as you suggested, unfortunately i cannot figure out how to access my deployed website.. the artifacts are zipped, so i guess i should access the files after i've deployed them to iis, but i cannot figure out the correct paths.. do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can take a look at a [Catalog of the built-in tasks for build-release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops).

The [Delete Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops) states: 
"Use this task in a build or release pipeline to delete files or folders from the agent working directory".

This may give you some ideas on how to achieve this.
I hope this help.

Comment: thank you, but i also need to rename the files, that task does not seem to be able to do that. Moreover i cannot figure out by what path to access the files deployed to iis

Comment: I was looking for that kind of solution, from what i just tryed, this can only delete files inside the artifact and not on the IIS Server.

Answer (score 0):

Comment on:

The Delete Files task states: "Use this task in a build or release pipeline to delete files or folders from the agent working directory".
and
".. from what I just tried, this can only delete files inside the artifact and not on the IIS Server."

That is correct for default behavior, but it has a parameter called SourceFolder, which has a default  as "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)". When you specify the SourceFolder to be "C:" you can enter a pattern to delete anything on the server. Might be wiser to use a bit more elaborate path then just c:\ but it works. Just tried it on a pipeline where a file needed to be deleted not from the workingfolder but from the deployed IIS location.

PS in a release pipeline the default seems to be the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) and not the $(Build.SourcesDirectory). Whether that is because the Build.SourcesDirectory defaults to System.DefaultWorkingDirectory in release pipelines or the task is being smart I don't know.